# Design MySQL table to get Improve SELECT speed

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, query-optimization

I'm designing simple support feature for a web site.
The user can open ticket with question and will get replays from the support stuff and other site users can also replay to his ticket.

The db will have 2 tables for this purpose, to simplify things I'll describe only relevant columns.

1. table **ticket_header** with columns:
   **ticket_id**(BIGINT, Primary), **email_ticket_owner**(VARCHAR), ...
2. table **tickets_comments** with columns:
   **number**(BIGINT), **ticket_id**(BIGINT), **email_ticket_commenter**(VARCHAR), ...

For each ticket there will be only one entry at table ticket_header and can be unlimited entries at table tickets_comments.
Each table expected to have large amounts of entries.

My question is:
What's the recommended way, performance wise, to define the indexes in table tickets_comments so I can SELECT all the entries with the same ticket_id as fast as possible from billions of entries.
My query will be:

```
SELECT *  
FROM   tickets_comments  
WHERE  ticket_id = 1234;
```

Comment: When possible, try and show your schema in `SHOW CREATE TABLE` form so we can build on what you already have. Those can be dropped into a local MySQL server for testing, or online tools like [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT *  
FROM tickets_comments  
WHERE ticket_id = 1234;
```

You want an index on `tickets_comments(ticket_id)`.

This might get tricky in terms of memory -- if your table and index don't both fit in memory.  You might want to select a limited number of columns -- and include those in the index.

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin, Do you mean to select INDEX under Index option for column ticket_id

Comment: @teachme . . . That may be one way to do it.  I would run `create index`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index for the ticket_id

> CREATE INDEX `idx_tickets_comments_ticket_id`  ON `tickets_comments` (ticket_id) COMMENT ''

Comment: You can change idx_tickets_comments_ticket_id to anything you want, and you can also add a comment at the end in between the single quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to improve... did you Build index on ticketid?